# MYSQL query select column string date compared to date formatted current date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

This is the query that I'm trying to run in my SQL phpMyAdmin to retrieve 2 rows of data:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(theDate, '%a, %b %e') = DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%a, %b %e')
```

I get no errors, also no results.  The format of the string in theDate column is like this for today's date:

```
Tue, Jan 20
```

What am I doing wrong in the conversions comparison?

Comment: What does `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(theDate, '%a, %b %c') FROM table;` output?

Comment: try to echo your query is your formatted data is correct?

Comment: Are you sure theDate is inserted as today's date(`STR_TO_DATE(theDate, '%a, %b %c')`) in database?

Comment: why don't you use `WHERE theDate=curdate()`?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I don't think that will work because `theDate` is a string.

Comment: `%c` is numeric month, surely you mean `%e` for numeric day instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is missing a year, which complicates date comparisons.  The best solution is probably to convert the current date to a string:

```
WHERE thedate = DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%a, %b %c')
```

You should use native date/time formats for these columns, not strings.

Comment: This worked...so even if `theDate` is a string, changing the format of `curdate()` works?  Comparing a string to a date?

Comment: @denikov . . . No, you are comparing a string to a string.  That is why the query uses `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Comment: So `DATE_FORMAT()` converts `curdate()` to a string?  Am I understanding that correctly now?

Comment: @denikov  . . . . Yes, you are understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`STR_TO_DATE()` creates a date from a string, while `CURDATE()` returns a date directly.

This should work:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(theDate, '%a, %b %c') = curdate()
```

Comment: Still no results because curdate() returns as stated `'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD format`

Comment: both `STR_TO_DATE()` and `CURDATE()` return the date in a YYYY-MM-DD format, so this definitely works. The problem is most probably, as Gordon statet in his answer, that your date string does not contain a year.

Answer (score 0):

`STR_TO_DATE(theDate, '%a, %b %c')` is convert date row string date into `Y-m-d` format

and you are trying to compare as in query

```
`%Y-%m-%d` = '%a, %b %c'
```

try this query if you want to compare date in other format

If `theDate`date store in format `Tue, Jan 20`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    theDate = 
       DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%a, %b %c')
```

Comment: Actually this is helpful.  I didn't know that `str_to_date` converts it that way.  I have to format my `date_format(curdate(), ...)`, right?

Comment: what is `theDate` column type??

Comment: The column type is a string